# Flow did not manage to include all participants

Tags: corda

first time posting here.
Getting into Cordapp development, checked out the Cordapp course on YouTube and followed the code demonstrated in the course.
Successfully deployed nodes, and everything was running fine, all the way up until I managed to execute a flow `TokenIssueFlowInitiator`.

It ran seamlessly at first, and I executed a flow in PartyA:

PartyA flow start

[image]

But when I went to run `vaultQuery`, all I had was the transaction in PartyA but not in the other participant PartyB.

Here is the result in PartyA:

PartyA run vaultQuery

[image]

But here is the result in PartyB:

[image]

I do not understand. I thought this might be an issue in the `TokenState` class, in the Participants list where I failed to add owner PartyB (run `vaultQuery` did not return participants list), but this is not the case, as I had included  `public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants()`. I do not understand what is going on. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Did you check the logs at PartyB node? You may get something useful there.

Comment: I copied and pasted the master example in the corda website and managed to execute it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include the link to the repository?

Comment: https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-openapi/blob/master/Solutions.md

Comment: Not sure what you did differently, the solutions work fine. Would be helpful if you could commit your code on github and share the same.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you were able to figure out the issue on your own. You correctly identified that you should have been able to see the token after a VaultQuery on PartyB.

If you're looking back at this later on the Bootcamp cordapp is available on GitHub and the solutions are on there as well.

https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp